# UIScrollView for ViewController horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, swift5

My code tutorial works for scrolling horizontally with ScrollView.
I would like to make it with ViewControllers (instead of views) from my Storyboard.
And I would like to add a vertical ScrollView (To move from center to right or left = ScrollView horizontal, and to move from center to top or bottom (vertically).

Is that possible? Could someone give me a hint ?

Thanks

For information, this is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    lazy var view0: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Page 0"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.edgeTo(view: view)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var view1: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Page 1"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.edgeTo(view: view)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var view2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Page 2"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.edgeTo(view: view)
        return view
    }()
    
    lazy var views = [view0, view1, view2]
    
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(views.count), height: view.frame.height)
        
        for i in 0..<views.count {
            scrollView.addSubview(views[i])
            views[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        }
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        return scrollView
    }()
    
    lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let pageControl = UIPageControl()
        pageControl.numberOfPages = views.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pageControlTapHandler(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return pageControl
    }()
    
    @objc
    func pageControlTapHandler(sender: UIPageControl) {
        scrollView.scrollTo(horizontalPage: sender.currentPage, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.edgeTo(view: view)
        
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        pageControl.pinTo(view)
    }


}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
    }
```

Comment: [container](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) seems to be what you need .

Comment: Try to do a better job explaining your goal. Are you going to have a "3x3 grid" of 9 views, so you can scroll left-right / up-down?